# mouse over and mouseout in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [preventing mouseout event for child node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151676/preventing-mouseout-event-for-child-node)

```
 <li id="profile-list">
            <a href="profile.html" class="main-menu" id="p">PROFILE </a>

             <div id="m1" class="sub-menu"  style="visibility: hidden;">
                  <a href="Profile-Value and beliefs.html">Value & Beliefs </a>
                  <a href="Profile-Quality.html">Quality</a>
                  <a href="Profile-Strategic.html">Strategic networks </a>

             </div>
 </li>
```

My Jquery is

```
$("#m1").mouseover(function () {
        $("#p").css({ 'background-image': "url(images/tab_bg.png)", 'background-repeat': "no-repeat", 'color': '#FFF' });      
    });
    $("#m1").mouseout(function () {
        $("#p").removeAttr("style");
    });
```

When I move the mouse on submenu link mainmenu link is animate.I don't want this.Please help!

Answer (score 1):

thinzar, your code look VERY complicated, try to refactor your posted code, I think your problem will look more simple if you do so.

Do always follow the good practices when posting your code to public websites.

1- post a complete, easy to ready code.

2- be precise about your problem, describe it with clear words.

3- we are all here to help, so help us to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to know exactly what you're talking about, especially without your CSS.
For your jQuery, perhaps something like this?

```
$("#m1").mouseover(
function () {
    $("#p").css({ 'background-image': "url(images/tab_bg.png)", 'background-repeat': "no-repeat", 'color': '#FFF' });      
}, function () {
    $("#p").removeAttr("style");
});

$("#m2").mouseover(
    function () {
    $("#s").css({ 'background-image': "url(images/tab_bg.png)", 'background-repeat': "no-repeat", 'color': '#FFF' });
}, function () {
    $("#s").removeAttr("style");
});
```