# Show div objects on mouse over?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a JavaScript function to say callout div and notch div are hidden but when mouse hovers over contact_details_email fade in callout and notch then on mouse out of contact_details_email fade out callout and notch.

I'm new to JavaScript, can someone please show me what I'd need to do?

```
<script>
     $(".callout").hide();
     $(".notch").hide();
        $('.contact_details_email').onMouseOver(function(){

                $('.callout').fadeIn(500);
                 $('.notch').fadeIn(500);


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you share your html as well?

Comment: Since you are using classes, and not ID's I'm guessing you want to fade the .callout and .notch divs that are specific to the parent div (.contact_details_email). Is this the case?

Comment: See my revised answer for targeting the appropriate child divs

Answer (score 0):

The general format for jQuery's mouseover event is as follows (as per the excellent documentation you can find at http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$(selector).hover(function(){
    //mouseover handler
}, function(){
    //mouseout handler
})
```

Assuming .callout and .notch are descendents of .contact_details_email...

```
$('.contact_details_email').hover(function(){
    //mouseover handler
    $(this).find('.callout').fadeIn(500);
    $(this).find('.notch').fadeIn(500);
}, function(){
    //mouseout handler
    $(this).find('.callout').fadeOut(500);
    $(this).find('.notch').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope   [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151676/preventing-mouseout-event-for-child-node#answer-1153476) useful for you  and helpful [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)